# Scanning CSV with text fields into Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parsing, csv

I have a CSV scanning method I found [here](http://pjeremymalouf.com/scan-a-csv-into-swift/). The SO answer that led me there is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802614/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-dictionary-from-a-txt-file-in-swift/28803913#28803913).

**My issue is**: The CSV data I am trying to scan occasionally contains commas (in a field called "Notes" as well as others). This presents a problem when I scan the csv, because it interprets the notes field as having seperated values in it.

**Can someone help me edit this method to properly handle commas inside of a text field?** I am also unsure of how to save the csv to delimit that field. Not sure where my exact changes need to made in this method and in the save options for the csv.

Here is the function straight from my app:

```
func scanCSV () -> Array<Dictionary<String,String>> {
    var myCSVContents = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

    //rawData is a global string variable that gets set to the CSV string on object init.
    let allRows = rawData.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    let headers = allRows[0].componentsSeparatedByString(",")

    runFunctionOnRowsFromFile(headers, withFunction: {
        (aRow: Dictionary<String, String>) in
        myCSVContents.append(aRow)
    })

    return myCSVContents

}
func runFunctionOnRowsFromFile(theColumnNames:Array<String>, withFunction theFunction:(Dictionary<String, String>)->()) {

    var fileObjectCleaned = rawData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: "\n")

    fileObjectCleaned = fileObjectCleaned.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n\n", withString: "\n")

    let objectArray = fileObjectCleaned.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")

    for anObjectRow in objectArray {

        let objectColumns = anObjectRow.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

        var aDictionaryEntry = Dictionary<String, String>()

        var columnIndex = 0

        for anObjectColumn in objectColumns {

            aDictionaryEntry[theColumnNames[columnIndex]] = anObjectColumn.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

            columnIndex++
        }

        if aDictionaryEntry.count>1{
            theFunction(aDictionaryEntry)
        }
    }
}
```

I realize this question has been asked before, but I am getting myself confused by the syntax differences that other languages have in those answers. I am a new programmer, if that isn't brutally obvious.

Comment: I'd recommend finding an existing CSV parser such as [this](https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV) or [this](https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV) and using that instead.

Comment: @Elogent - do you know whether either of these explicitly handles the condition I'm struggling with? In the readme files they don't come right out and say they do

Comment: The first one says it conforms to [rfc4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2), so I would assume so.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, if you post this as an answer, after I test I will accept it so you get some credit!

Comment: Not sure how much of my answer is stuff you already knew, but it's there for completeness anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate your time in making a nice thorough answer, no matter how much I THINK i know haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when dealing with commonly used formats such as CSV, it is preferable to find and use an existing library. There already exist a couple in Swift, such as [CSwiftV](https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV) and [SwiftCSV](https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV) (the former of which adheres to the [rfc4180 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2)).

The reason for this is that some of the details in common tasks (whatever the task itself may be) are going to be at least a bit tricky to get right, so by using an existing library instead of writing it yourself, you can minimize the number of people who actually *need* to get it right.